# How to change title attribute of a Select using Bootstrap 4 with jQuery in real time?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, html-select

How to change title attribute of a Select using Bootstrap 4 with jQuery in real time? See this code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group disabled">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="test" id="my-select">
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I tried to change the title using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-select').prop('title', 'new content');
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-select').attr('title', 'new content');
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

But nothing happens! How to solve it?

Comment: look, it's working. https://jsfiddle.net/gd80x71o/ .

Comment: It's working in my PC. Are you sure, you have added jQuery library properly?

Comment: Is there any other tag with the same id? Because i´m the third one that have tested and it´s working

Comment: it's working fine. Please make sure there are no no-repeat id's

Comment: You all are right! I corrected the code and I put an example here https://jsfiddle.net/x5mp7deu/ ... pass your cursor over Select, see TITLE, and after click on button, and pass cursor over Select again. You'll see what I'm saying. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try yhis:

```
$( "#my-select" ).attr({
  title: "new content"
});
```

Comment: I saw your example. JavaScript code works without problems!

Comment: Yeah, I agree, the JavaScript code works, but the effect is not what expected. Check it if you want. Open the example again, stay your mouse over the Select (you'll see the bootstrap tooltip with message TEST), then click on the button, and back to stay your mouse over the Select (see that the bootstrap tooltip haven't change to NEW CONTENT, instead, both TEST and NEW CONTENT appears at different ways). Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: You should change the [data-original-title] attribute in the [select]. attr('data-original-title', 'NEW CONTENT') The Bootstrap tooltip works based on the [data-original-title] attribute value. After running the [.tooltip()] method, the [data-original-title] attribute is automatically added to the tag by Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#my-select').attr('title', 'new content');
});
```

replace with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#my-select').attr('title', 'new content');
$('#my-select').selectpicker('destroy').selectpicker();
});
```

you need to include this js also

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.10/js/bootstrap-select.js" ></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group disabled">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-style="select-with-transition" title="test" id="my-select">
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would recommend adding a bit of explanation to your code.